# dealing with unbalanced training data: validation results differ from training

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification

I need to train a binary classifier with unbalanced data (about 3000 images in the 'ok' set and 160 in the 'ko' set). Moreover, I want to minimize false negative much more than false positive.

For this reason I weighted 20 times the 'ko' images and the training (80% of the dataset) went very well (3 false negative and 15 false positive: accuracy > 99%). However, on the validation dataset I have 19 false negative and 7 false positive, with nearly 96% of accuracy.

96% accuracy is ok for me, but I would like to obtain less false negative.

What can I try to do?

Comment: Issue might be because of Overfitting problem, take a look at [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit) to know how to avoid overfitting and underfitting problem in Tensorflow

Comment: Yes, I agree that in some sense it can be overfitting: however, it looks different from "ordinary" overfitting since both loss and accuracy are consistent for train and validation, while recall and precision are not. Ordinary countermeasures against overfitting work essentially on loss: they do not work in this case.